# How to solve this SQL specific merge problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to solve the error:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

```
merge CARD_ALERTS as t
using @tblAlerts as s
on (t.Id = s.AlertId and t.CardId = s.CardId)
when not matched by target
    then insert(Id, ExternalCodeHolder, CardId, IsCardOwner, IBAN, PAN, MinAmount, Currency, ByEmail, BySMS, IssueDate, IsActive)
        values(s.AlertId, s.ExternalCodeHolder, s.CardId, s.IsCardOwner, s.IBAN, s.PAN, s.MinAmount, s.Currency, s.ByEmail, s.BySMS, getdate(), 1)
when matched 
    then update set t.ByEmail = s.ByEmail, t.BySMS = s.BySMS, IsActive = 1, t.MinAmount = s.MinAmount
when not matched by source and t.Id=@AlertId 
    then update set t.IsActive = 3
```

Comment: The error message is relatively clear, and without any data to go on, or schema, it isn't really possible to tell you what is wrong in your on predicate.

Comment: The description says it all so find the unique combination of columns which would be granular.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the error message and in the comments, multiple rows of the source table correspond to the same row in the target one.

This will show you which rows of the target table have multiple rows from the source table that try to update them:

```
select t.Id,t.CardId,count(*) as [count]
from CARD_ALERTS as t
inner join @tblAlerts as s
on (t.Id = s.AlertId and t.CardId = s.CardId)
group by t.Id,t.CardId
having count(*)>1
```

This will also show you the multiple rows of the source table:

```
select t.*,s.*
from CARD_ALERTS as t
inner join @tblAlerts as s on (t.Id = s.AlertId and t.CardId = s.CardId)
inner join
(
    select ca.Id,ca.CardId
    from CARD_ALERTS as ca
    inner join @tblAlerts as s
    on (ca.Id = s.AlertId and ca.CardId = s.CardId)
    group by ca.Id,ca.CardId
    having count(*)>1
)tkey on t.Id=tkey.Id and t.CardId=tkey.CardId
```